# Getting a Delphi TTimer to work with a multi-threading app

Tags: multithreading, delphi, timer, vcl, omnithreadlibrary

I have an issue with a simple TTimer that's **initiated and have its OnTimer event executed in the main app thread**, the code looks like this:

```
procedure TForm1.DoSomeStuff();
begin
     OmniLock.Acquire;
     try
        Parallel.Pipeline.NumTasks(MaxThreads).Stage(StageProc).Run;

        if (MyTimer = nil) then
        begin
             MyTimer := TTimer.Create(nil);
             MyTimer.Interval := 60 * 1000;  // timer fired every 60 seconds
             MyTimer.OnTimer := MyTimerEvent;
             MyTimer.Enabled := True;
         end;
      finally
             OmniLock.Release;
      end;    // try/finally
 end;
```

Everthing work just fine when I execute the code in a simple project/demo, but in my app (which uses Omni Thread Library v3), the timer event is **never fired**

I'm pretty sure **it's nothing**, I just can't figure out what's wrong!

I triple checked: `MyTimer` is only assigned once in my code, its OnTimer event is correctly assigned, etc...

I'm using Delphi 2010

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: can you show how DoSomeStuff is called

Comment: It's called from another function in the main form, nothing fancy: just a simple `DoSomeStuff();` call. And, I'm only calling it **once** in my app

Comment: Is it called from an event handler perhaps? Why won't you tell us?

Comment: If 'initiated and have its OnTimer event executed in the main app thread', why is there a lock around it?

Comment: Thank you David and Martin...my code was like `FormCreate() --> LoadApp() --> Scan() --> DoSomeStuff()`, I moved the timer initialization to the function `Scan()`, **removed the locking** and now everything works just fine

Comment: There should be no reason (OmniThreadLibrary-wise) for this behaviour. Pipeline.Run is nonblocking and should not affect your timer creation. If you can create a small program that is not working correctly, I'd be glad to look at it to see if this is a bug in the OTL that is causing the problem.

Comment: BTW, as your are running one stage on mulitple threads, better abstractions may be ForEach, ParallelTask or BackgroundWorker.

Comment: @gabr: `LoadApp()` & `Scan()` routines are not meant to be multi-threaded. I'll try to reproduce this on a smaller scale & see if I can reproduce the issue...

Comment: @gabr PS. Does your suggestion still applies if I'm using it [in this context](http://otl.17slon.com/forum/index.php/topic,354.0.html)?

Comment: @Gdhami Yes, BackgroundWorker is basically a single-stage pipeline with additional cancellation mechanism. I'm not saying that using Pipeline is this context is wrong, it's just that there may be a more appropriate mechanism built into the OTL.

Comment: Thank you gabr, I'll take a look at BackgroundWorker!

Answer (score 7):

`TTimer` is a message based timer.  Whatever thread context the `TTimer` is created in must have an active message loop in order for `TTimer` to process its `WM_TIMER` messages.

`TTimer` is not a thread-safe timer.  In order to receive the `WM_TIMER` messages, it has to allocate an `HWND` window handle for itself.  It does so using the VCL's `AllocateHWnd()` function, which is not thread-safe and must not be called from outside the context of the main thread.

If you need a thread-safe timer, either call `CreateWindow()` directly and pump/process the `WM_TIMER` messages directly, or else use a different timer mechanism, such as a threaded multimedia timer via `timeSetEvent()`, or even just a simple busy loop via `Sleep()` or `WaitForSingleObject()`.  Without knowing what you are using the timer for, it is difficult to pin-point an alternative that suits your needs.

Comment: According to the question, the timer is created in the main thread. That's what that bold text says.

Comment: Thank you Remy, I'm not sure but maybe the fact that I initialized the timer (in the main thread but) **just after** I called the OmniThreadLibrary (using the `Paralell.Pipeline...run()` code) caused the issue, moving the initialization code to a different routine fixed this

Comment: Sounds like Omni was blocking the main thread from processing messages.

Comment: Does parallel.pipeline.run return immediately or is it a blocking call?